# i cant stop the timer, it does not stop repeating itself

Tags: java, android, timertask

I can not stop the timer, although I used conditional is the only thing that does not stop repeating, I do not know where to put the timer.cancel or timer.purgue
When Nrepetir = false, the task dont repeat more, pero the timer dont stop, i will tried purgue,cancel and task.cancel or conditional but always repeat.
HERE ARE ALL THE METHODS:

```
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(Nrepetir==true) {
                Nrepetir=false;
                AsyncHttpClient clienteTurno = new AsyncHttpClient();
                RequestParams rpTurno = new RequestParams();
                rpTurno.put("IdPartida", IdPartida);
                rpTurno.put("IdUsuario", IdUsuario);


                clienteTurno.get(urlTurno, rpTurno, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                        if (statusCode == 200) {
                            String respuesta = response.toString();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            ComprobarTurno turno = gson.fromJson(respuesta, ComprobarTurno.class);

                            int res = turno.getSuccess();
                            Log.d("DEBUG - MENSAJE TURNO", turno.getMessage());
                            //Si es correcta

                            turnoJugador = turno.getPosicion();
                            turnoActual = turno.getTurno();
                            valorRecibidoReal = turno.getValorRecibidoReal();
                            valorRecibido = turno.getValorRecibido();


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
                        return false;
                    }




                });

                AsyncHttpClient clienteCorreos = new AsyncHttpClient();
                RequestParams rpCorreos = new RequestParams();
                rpCorreos.put("IdPartida", IdPartida);

                clienteCorreos.get(urlCorreos, rpCorreos, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                        if (statusCode == 200) {
                            String respuesta = response.toString();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            CorreosPartida correos = gson.fromJson(respuesta, CorreosPartida.class);
                            int res = correos.getSuccess();


                            lista.addAll(correos.getCorreos());
                            Log.d("DEBUG - NOMBRE1", lista.get(0));;
                            Log.d("DEBUG - NOMBRE2", lista.get(1));;


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
                        return false;
                    }
                });


                AsyncHttpClient clienteFallos = new AsyncHttpClient();
                RequestParams rpFallos = new RequestParams();
                rpFallos.put("IdPartida", IdPartida);

                clienteFallos.get(urlFallos, rpFallos, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                        if (statusCode == 200) {
                            String respuesta = response.toString();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            FallosPartida fallos = gson.fromJson(respuesta, FallosPartida.class);
                            Log.d("DEBUG - FALLOS", fallos.getMessage());

                            for (String s : fallos.getFallos()) {
                                listaFallosVariable.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
                                Log.d("DEBUG - FALLOS", s);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }else {
                Log.d("DEBUG - TIMER CANCEL", String.valueOf(Nrepetir));

                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    };

    Log.d("DEBUG - BOOLEAN", String.valueOf(Nrepetir));

        timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);
```

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem, could you reformulate a question. As far as I understand something unexpected happens after activity restart.

Comment: the problem would be that the timer task repeats all the activity, not only the part of the code that is inside it, therefore the boolean variables with which I control that stop or do certain things always return to their initial value and the timer task never ends

Comment: You create a new copy of your `new Runnable` every time your `TimerTask` fires.

Comment: How could I avoid it? It's the only thing that fails me to finish the application

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. It runs a new TimerTask everytime you execute your code thats why it will run as many times as you execute it. The thing i did to prevent this was to create another column from my database which checks if the schedule is already on queue with the timer task. For example:

After running the timerTask, change status to 1, then after its executed, change it to 0. It would work if have a conditional statement on which your timertask will only run if the status is 0.

You can also do this by using a global variable or array, whichever you want and whichever you're comfortable with.

Comment: if(Nrepetir == true) {
            task = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    //    public void run() {
                    try {        }
            };

            Nrepetir = noRepetir;
            timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);


        } 
I understand the solution you give me but I would not know how to apply it, this is what I have tried but it does not work, Nrepetir is the local variable, repetir and no repetir the globals.

Comment: How are you accessing the global variable? Make sure you're not instantiating the global variable when you call it as it will only reset its value.

Comment: First i create this local variable private boolean  Nrepetir = repetir(global)  

This is the timertask 
 handler = new Handler();
        timer = new Timer();

        if(Nrepetir == repetir) {
            task = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

     CODE

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                 final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PartidaOnlineActivity.this);
                                 if (turnoActual.equalsIgnoreCase(turnoJugador)) {

                                    Nrepetir = noRepetir(global);

     CODE

  }
            }; END TASK

        } END IF
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);

Comment: Are you calling Nrepitir = repitir(global) when you call your function?

Comment: yes, i tried all i think, now i am debbug method to method

Comment: Have you tried array manipulation with this? for example, you create an ID for every task you're gonna do, and before running your timer, check every index of your GLOBAL array if your ID already exists in that array. Maybe something like this might work. Its the same concept i did with my problem but i used database for this.

Comment: I tried whit the global variable but doesnt work,  and whit your comment, if the ID exists in the array, what i do? , Can I send the code to you in some other way more clearly?